# Can someone give me information about conway base 13 function and give me a graph of the function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, algebraic-topology, cantor-set

I have encountered this function while trying to construct a function that is discontinuous everywhere but has IVP.But the function is not clear to me.I need a proper explanation about the definition and graph of the function

Comment: The graph of the function looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zmOf.png

Comment: Have you read the Wikipeaid article on the [Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function)? If not, go and read it now. And then please explain what it is that you don't understand. We are not mind-readers!

Comment: I've voted to close because this is a duplicate of one of the very earliest questions on the site. There are other questions about it too, found by searching "Conway base 13"

Comment: Rahul I opened the above link but there is no graph only a black screen.Please can you once again send a graph of conway base 13.

Comment: Kishalay, that is really the graph of the function! It takes all values on every interval, so its graph is dense everywhere. @Rahul was making a little joke, I think, but one with a point to it.

Answer (score 1):

The Conway base $13$ function is a artificial function that encodes decimal representations as base $13$ representations. If the base $13$ representation of $x$ encodes the decimal representation of $y$ then $f(x)=y$. If the base $13$ representation of $x$ does not encode any decimal representation (which is the case for "most" numbers) then $f(x)=0$.

The encoding is constructed in such a way that between any pair of real numbers there is an encoding (in fact, an infinite number of encodings) of every possible decimal representation. Since every real number $y$ has a decimal representation, this means that in any interval $[a,b]$ there is some $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=y$. And this implies the IVP.

The only significance of $13$ is that it is $3$ greater than $10$, thus providing $3$ additional digits $A,B,C$ (or $+, -, .$ in Conway's original formulation) on top of the decimal digits $0 \dots 9$ to support the encoding rules.